# Cannot change DataType of a column once it has data

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, types, dataview

I want to sort a gridview by a datetime-column so I need to change the datatype of that column

I try it with following code but I'm getting the error:

```
dt.DefaultView.Table.Columns["Meldingsdatum"].DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");

dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Meldingsdatum asc";
gvOutlookMeldingen.DataSource = dt;
gvOutlookMeldingen.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why is the column in the source data not a `DateTime` to start with?

Comment: You can click the datetimeheader and it will sort asc and desc...

Comment: it doesn't sort it as a datetime, but as a string. So I have to change it's type and sort it as a datetime

Comment: Yes, but why is it being read in from the database as a string when you clearly want it to be a datetime? Cast it to a datetime in the SQL query rather than trying to manipulate it afterwards.

Comment: I don't read it from any database.

Comment: *Wherever* you read the data from, make sure that the `Meldingsdatum` column is the correct data type (`DateTime`) before you populate the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know here; *either* (and preferred) make the column a `DateTime` **initially** (and importantly: before you load data), or hack around it. By which I mean perhaps add a *second* column (`DateTime`), and push the data accross - inefficient and extra work for no good reason.